# Variables to input in file name for Reporting Services subscriptions

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

Is there a list anywhere that lists all the variables I can use in file names for report subscriptions from within SQL Server Management Studio? I currently use `@timestamp` in my file names, but would like to use other options or even remove parts of the time stamp (for example, just use the date, not the time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `@timestamp` is the only variable available.  There are various workarounds for formatting `@timestamp`, but nothing that is simple.  Here is a thread that explains one (but not the only) workaround:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/81f47009-946a-4ebc-be43-7690236e829b

In case that link goes away, here were the recommendations:

> To solve the issue, I would suggest using Data-Driven Subscription
>
> A data-driven subscription provides a way to use dynamic subscription
>   data that is retrieved from an external data source at run time. A
>   data-driven subscription can also use static text and default values
>   that you specify when the subscription is defined. We can use
>   data-driven subscriptions to do the following:
>
> Distribute a report to a fluctuating list of subscribers. For example,
>   you can use data-driven subscriptions to distribute a report
>   throughout a large organization where subscribers vary from one month
>   to the next, or use other criteria that determines group membership
>   from an existing set of users. Filter the report output using report
>   parameter values that are retrieved at run time. Vary report output
>   formats and delivery options for each report delivery. .
>
> In this case, we can define the filename with timestamp in database
>   and then use Data-Driven Subscriptions to delivey the report.
>
> For more information about Data-Driven Subscriptions, please see:
>
> For SQL Server Reporting Services 2005:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150(SQL.90).aspx
>
> For SQL Server Reporting Services 2008:
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, and that link is helpful.